# Dealing with json type data in a template

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am after some advice.  I know what I need to do, but not sure how I can do it

I send data to a template that comes from from a database

Let's say the database has two fields

```
Field one (name)
Name of a person
```

Field two some json (the json has a structure like this, with many field:value)

```
{  
   "field1":"value1",
   "field2":"value2"
}
```

I can output this as

```
Field one (name)    Field two (json)
```

What I actually want to do though, is loop through the json, and print out the values, so like this

```
Name of a person    field1|field2
```

I am a bit lost on how I can do that

I tried something like this

```
{% for anitem in fieldtwo %}
<div>{{ anitem }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

But that just seems to print out each character

Is what I need to do achievable?  I am thinking I just have the whole approach wrong

Thanks

Grant

Comment: Are you using a particular templating language?

Comment: I am am not, only for the reason that I haven't before.  I am relatively new to Python.  I am more than happy to take some advice.

Comment: So the `{% %}` was purely hypothetical?

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding.  I am just using the standard template functionality (rather than something like Jinja2).  Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I ended up using another dictionary and then pass that through to the template

I loop through the queryset in the view to populate the dictionary

In the template I then did this (alloweddomains is from the view)

```
        {% for testcaseid, domains in alloweddomains.items %}
            {% if listtestcase.id == testcaseid %}
                {% for key, value in domains.items %}
                    <div><a class="sendtolinkdisabled" data-testcasename="{{ listtestcase.name }}" data-testcaseid="{{ $
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

This basically looped through the dictionary and if there was a match to my unique ID I get the data and do something with it

I tried various ways to not need the if statement and just get the right point in the dictionary, but nothing seemed to work (so I took the if approach)

Grant